# Does open street map support an earth View?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-earth

I would like to know if open street map supports an earth View
like google maps.

In the official website, I can see 5 different layers but I can't see an earth View.

So, does open street map support an earth View?

Cause I read somewhere about .kmz files and open street map in google earth and I got a bit confused.

Can someone elaborate on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) I'm sorry but your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A and your question doesn't seem to include anything about programming. It would be much **better to ask your question at http://help.openstreetmap.org/**.

(b) No, OpenStreetMap doesn't offer an aerial-photo view. *(Bing lets OSM use their aerial imagery while editing, but that's all.)* But OSM is not a project to provide aerial photos. (Also, KMZ files hold geodata - they don't have any connection to aerial imagery either.)